# How to use line chart (highcharts) in angular with backend data (springboot and mssql)

Tags: sql-server, angular, spring-boot, highcharts

how to display highcharts series{ data:[] } from the backend db.
though the connection is established. how to map the data is what i couldn't find

Iam using angular10 as frontend and backend as springboot with mssql server.

Comment: This link has required information for https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/

Comment: Hi @sugi raj, Please add more details about the problem. What is the data structure you receive from backend?